# can't run console program in batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have a batch file (`run.bat`) which is to change my IP address setting:

```
netsh
interface
ip
set address "lan" static 192.168.30.77 255.255.255.0 192.168.30.2
```

The command worked as I expected when I type it directly in a `cmd` shell, but not when I put it in `run.bat` (which I ran with administrator access).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

When you type `netsh` at the Command Prompt (`cmd`) prompt,
you start running the `netsh.exe` program. 
The next three lines are input to that program,
and are read and processed by that program.

`cmd` isn't set up to allow that sort of thing in a `.BAT` file. 
But you can do the following workaround to make the `netsh`-related commands
*be* input to `netsh`:

```
(echo interface & echo ip & echo set address "lan" static 192.168.30.77 255.255.255.0 192.168.30.2) | netsh
```

To make your script more readable, break the long line with a `^`:

```
(echo interface & echo ip & echo set address "lan" ^
  static 192.168.30.77 255.255.255.0 192.168.30.2) | netsh
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the entire command on one line so that it gets passed to the `netsh` executable.

`netsh interface ip set address "lan" static 192.168.30.77 255.255.255.0 192.168.30.2`